# Numerical example of Generalized Least Squares

Tags: regression, econometrics, generalized-least-squares

I am going through the concepts of GLS and its estimation process and have completely understood the "Generalized Methodology".
I just wonder how a numerical example can be solved manually(on paper/by hand).
for the estimation of `b=(X'v^-1 X)^-1 * X'V^-1 Y` ,
I need a numerical example with fewer observations for the sake of practice to get my self going through the methodology.
i) So, if you can provide my with such example that would be so great!!!
ii) Any example with the provided matrix " V^-1 " will be helpful.
Any kind of help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: http://halweb.uc3m.es/esp/Personal/personas/durban/esp/web/notes/gls.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps one of the simplest possible cases is:

- you're simply estimating the mean of $y_i$
- the observations are uncorrelated
- there's heteroskedasticity, the variance of $y_i$ is $\sigma_i^2$

Then $X = \mathbf{1}$ and $V = \mathrm{diag}\left( \sigma^2_1, \sigma^2_2, \ldots, \sigma^2_n \right)$. The GLS estimate simplifies to:

\begin{align*}
\hat{\mathbf{b}} &= \sum_i \alpha_i y_i \quad \quad \text{where } \alpha_i = \frac{1/\sigma^2_i}{\sum_j 1 / \sigma_j^2}
\end{align*}

that is, observations are weighted by the inverse of the variance.